# Python: plot panda dataframe with groupby - weird output

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe (of type object, for reasons of inserting lists in certain steps beforehand) with three columns looking like this

```
    data  stimulus trial
0   2     -2       1
1   2     -2       2
2   2     -2       3
3   2     -2       4
4   2     -2       5
5   2     -2       6
6   1     -2       7
...
159 1     2.5      16
```

Currently I'm using seaborn but I'm having difficulties inserting proper legends to my plot.

```
# spi_num is my dataframe
sns.swarmplot(x="stimulus", y="data", data=spi_num.astype(np.float), edgecolor="black", linewidth=.9)
sns.boxplot(x="stimulus", y="data", data=spi_num.astype(np.float), saturation=1)
```

[image]

So I have two questions. How do I smoothly integrate a legend with seaborn? And how would I get this plot using pandas plot commands? I thought I would need something like this:

```
spi_num.astype(np.float).groupby('stimulus').plot.box()
```

But then I get 10 figures (one for each stimulus) with 3 boxplots for each xlabel i.e. "data", "stimulus" and "trial". Shouldn't this give me a plot like shown above? At least [he does it like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy0fDqoMJx8&t=109s) .

[image]

---

## Build my dataframe

```
trial_vec    = np.tile(np.arange(16)+1, 10)     
stimulus_vec = np.repeat([-2., -1.75, -1., -0.75, -0.5,  0.5,  1.,  1.25,  1.75,  2.5 ], 16)                  
data_vec     = np.random.randint(0, 16, size=160)
spi_num      = pd.DataFrame({'trial': trial_vec, 'stimulus': stimulus_vec, 'data': data_vec}).astype('object')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `DataFrame.boxplot` to get the desired box plot

```
spi_num.astype(np.float).boxplot(column="data", by="stimulus")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! So easy. Do you also know how to add legens in seaborn plots?

Comment: That is a totally different question. Did you google "seaborn legend"?

Comment: I know but I posted both, that's why I'm asking. Yeah I googled but it looked all too complicated to be the only solution.

Comment: You should not post two questions in one question - that alone is usually reason enough to close a question on SO as "too broad". My strategy is usually to just pick the one question which seems to be the harder one to solve or the one which shows some attempted solution and ignore the other(s).

Comment: All right, I'll copy paste it to a new question then. Thanks for the harder question then!